# Check if each row in a pandas series contains a string from a list using apply?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

I'm trying to add a column to the DF, depending on whether other column's value contains any of the strings in a list.

The list is:

```
services = [
        "TELECOM",
        "AYSA",
        "PERSONAL"
]
```

And so far I've tried:

```
payments["category"] = "services" if payments["concept"].contains(service for service in services) else ""
```

And this:

```
payments["category"] = payments["concept"].apply(lambda x: "services" if x.contains(service) for service in services) else ""
```

Among some other variations... I've seen other questions but they're mostly related to the opposite problem (checking whether a column's value is contained by a string in a list)

I could use your help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` and `str.contains`:

```
payments['category'] = np.where(payments['concept'].str.contains('|'.join(services)),
                                'services', '')
```

Output:

```
        concept  category
0       TELECOM  services
1          AYSA  services
2      PERSONAL  services
3  other things
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! But would be possible to skip rows where other category has already be defined? I'm trying to run a second line like `payments['category'] = np.where((payments['concept'].str.contains('|'.join(online_shopping))) & (payments["category"] == ''), 'online_shopping', '')` but that second condition isn't working...

Comment: In that case, you should use np.select which allows multiple conditions.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use isin

```py
payments['category'] = np.where(
    payments['concept'].isin(services),
    'services', '')
```

```py
import pandas
import numpy

dic = {"concept": ["TELECOM", "NULL"]}

payments = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)

payments["category"] = numpy.where(payments["concept"].isin(["TELECOM", "AYSA", "PERSONAL"]), "services", "")

print(payments)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but thank you for the quick answer!!

Comment: @D. Seah, ``isin`` func is not allowed on ``StringMethods``