# Python Pandas: check if Series contains a string from list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to identify if a column `Blaze[Info]` contains within the text a string from a list (and create a new Boolean column with that information).

The DataFrame looks like:

```
       Word          Info
0      Aam           Aam, n. Etym: [D. aam, fr. LL. ama; cf. L. ham...
1      aard-vark     Aard"-vark`, n. Etym: [D., earth-pig.] (Zoöl.)
2      aard-wolf     Aard"-wolf`, n. Etym: [D, earth-wolf] (Zoöl.)
```

When I state the term directly I get the answer I want:

`Blaze['Noun'] = np.where((Blaze['Info'].str.contains('n.')),True,False)`
`Blaze['Verb'] = np.where((Blaze['Info'].str.contains('v.')),True,False)`

```
       Word          Info                                                Noun   Verb
0      Aam           Aam, n. Etym: [D. aam, fr. LL. ama; cf. L. ham...   True   False
1      aard-vark     Aard"-vark`, n. Etym: [D., earth-pig.] (Zoöl.)      True   False
2      aard-wolf     Aard"-wolf`, n. Etym: [D, earth-wolf] (Zoöl.)       True   False
```

but this is not scalable as I have 100+ features to search for.

When I iterate through the list `abbreviation` :

```
abbreviation=['n'., 'v.']
col_name=['Noun','Verb']

for i in range(len(abbreviation)):
    Blaze[col_name[i]] = np.where((Blaze['Info'].str.contains(abbreviation[i])), True, False)
```

I am returned  DataFrame full of 'FALSE' entries:

```
       Word          Info                                                Noun   Verb
0      Aam           Aam, n. Etym: [D. aam, fr. LL. ama; cf. L. ham...   False  False
1      aard-vark     Aard"-vark`, n. Etym: [D., earth-pig.] (Zoöl.)      False  False
2      aard-wolf     Aard"-wolf`, n. Etym: [D, earth-wolf] (Zoöl.)       False  False
```

I can see several answers for doing something similar but grouping the answer in a single row:
[Check if each row in a pandas series contains a string from a list using apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124303/check-if-each-row-in-a-pandas-series-contains-a-string-from-a-list-using-apply)

[Scalable solution for str.contains with list of strings in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937697/scalable-solution-for-str-contains-with-list-of-strings-in-pandas)

but I don't think these solve the above.

Is anyone able to explain how I am going wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me -- the only thing you need to do is pass `regex=False` a s`.` is a regex character meaning the second row would be `True` since there is a `z` in it. There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing the loop, but I think my way may be slightly more pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the lists simultaneously with `zip`. Make sure to pass `regex=False` to `str.contains` as `.` is a regex character.

```
abbreviation=['n.', 'v.']
col_name=['Noun','Verb']
for a, col in zip(abbreviation, col_name):
    Blaze[col] = np.where(Blaze['Info'].str.contains(a, regex=False),True,False)
Blaze
Out[1]: 
        Word                                               Info  Noun   Verb
0        Aam  Aam, n. Etym: [D. aam, fr. LL. ama; cf. L. ham...  True  False
1  aard-vark     Aard"-vark`, n. Etym: [D., earth-pig.] (Zoöl.)  True  False
2  aard-wolf      Aard"-wolf`, n. Etym: [D, earth-wolf] (Zoöl.)  True  False
```

If required, `str.contains` also has a `case` parameter, so you can specify `case=False` to search case-insensitively.